# RelativeLayout with nested layouts and Android

Tags: android, eclipse

My question is this:
In android programming can nest a layout in a layout?
The problem I have run into is my application is crashing and the only thing I have added is:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    newSheetLayoutH.setLayoutParams(params);
```

newSheetLayoutH is the layout nested in another layout.

My aim is to create a second layout (which is the one in question), that layout will be placed at the bottom of the main layout which is newSheetLayoutV, and centred(not mandatory to centre but appreciated).

Also if there is a way to potentially throw the buttons (three buttons) into the bottom corner of the newSheetLayoutV along the horizontal layout.

If more information is needed I will do my best to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the kind of layout in which newSheetLayoutH is nested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the kind of layout in which newSheetLayoutH is nested in?

***Make sure that the following is true***

When you want to set the Layout Parameters  (`LayoutParams`) of a certain view, the kind of these LayoutParams should be the same as the parent of the view you want to set the LayoutParams for.

For example, if you have a parent of kind LinearLayout, any child should have LayoutParams of kind LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: Does this mean that you could have to have the same:
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

In both layouts?

Comment: it is pretty clear. The LayoutParams you use should (for example) either be LinearLayout.LayoutParams or RelativeLayout.LayoutParams depending on the parent (whether it is LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in this case)

Comment: Ah I get you thanks. Pretty much had a mismatch with the formats :S